# Validar contraseñas en formulario

Tags: javascript, html5

Estoy creando un formulario para cambiar la contraseña en mi web, el formulario muestra una ayuda visual a los usuarios para que cumplan con la complejidad de la contraseña. En general funciona bien, pero si el usuario simplemente hace <kbd>tab</kbd> sin escribir ni confirmar la contraseña el script lo valida como que **- Ambas contraseñas son ambas son iguales -** Ya que ambos campos están vacíos.

[image: Ayuda validación complejidad contraseña]

Me gustaría que el script validara si las contraseñas son iguales solo si los campos no están vacíos.

Este es el código de mi javascript y html

```js
$(document.registration).ready(function() {

  $('input').keyup(function() {
    // set password variable
var password = $(this).val();
var p1 = document.getElementById("password1").value;
var p2 = document.getElementById("password2").value;
var noValido = / /;

//validar longitud contraseña
if ( password.length < 8 ) {
    $('#length').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
} else {
    $('#length').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
}
//validar letra
if ( password.match(/[A-z]/) ) {
    $('#letter').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
} else {
    $('#letter').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
}

//validar letra mayúscula
if ( password.match(/[A-Z]/) ) {
    $('#capital').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
} else {
    $('#capital').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
}

//validar numero
if ( password.match(/\d/) ) {
    $('#number').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
} else {
    $('#number').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
}

//validar confirmación contraseña
if (p1.length == 0 || p2.length == 0) {
  $('#null').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
} else {
  $('#null').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
}

//validar contraseñas cohincidan
if (p1 != p2) {
  $('#match').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
} else {
  $('#match').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
}

if(noValido.test(p1 || p2)){ // se chequea el regex de que el string no tenga espacio
  $('#blank').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
} else {
  $('#blank').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
}

}).focus(function() {
    $('#pswd_info').show();
}).blur(function() {
    $('#pswd_info').hide();
});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="password" name="password1" id="password1" class="form-control" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Ingresa tu contraseña">
<label for="password-confirm">Confirmar contraseña</label>
<input type="password" name="password-confirm" id="password2" class="form-control" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Confirma tu contraseña">
<div id="pswd_info">
  <h4>La contraseña debe cumplir los siguientes requerimientos:</h4>
  <ul>
    <li id="letter" class="invalid">Al menos <strong>una letra</strong></li>
    <li id="capital" class="invalid">Al menos <strong>una letra mayúscula</strong></li>
    <li id="number" class="invalid">Al menos <strong>un número</strong></li>
    <li id="length" class="invalid">Al menos <strong>8 carácteres</strong></li>
    <li id="null" class="invalid">Debe <strong>confirmar la contraseña</strong></li>
    <li id="match" class="invalid">Las contraseñas <strong>deben cohincidir</strong></li>
    <li id="blank" class="invalid">Las contraseñas <strong>no deben tener espacios</strong></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Pues valida primero que no estén vacíos los campos `if(password != ""){}` y ahí sí interactuar  con el campo

Comment: al perder el foco en el segundo texto puedes lanzar la validacion, pero es mas recomendable cuando presiones un boton de registro o envio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trata de validar siempre primero que los campos no estén vacíos, ya que el empieza a ejecutar cada una de las cosas que le pides que valide, pero pues, es irrelevante ya que los campos están vacíos, entonces en ese caso algo así estaría bien.

```js
$(document.registration).ready(function() {

  $('input').keyup(function() {
    // set password variable
    var password = $(this).val();
    var p1 = document.getElementById("password1").value;
    var p2 = document.getElementById("password2").value;
    var noValido = / /;


    //validar longitud contraseña
    if ( password.length < 8 ) {
        $('#length').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
    } else {
        $('#length').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
    }
    //validar letra
    if ( password.match(/[A-z]/) ) {
        $('#letter').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
    } else {
        $('#letter').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
    }

    //validar letra mayúscula
    if ( password.match(/[A-Z]/) ) {
        $('#capital').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
    } else {
        $('#capital').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
    }

    //validar numero
    if ( password.match(/\d/) ) {
        $('#number').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
    } else {
        $('#number').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
    }

    if(p1 != "" && p2 != ""){

      //validar confirmación contraseña
      if (p1.length == 0 || p2.length == 0) {
        $('#null').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
      } else {
        $('#null').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
      }

      //validar contraseñas cohincidan
      if (p1 != p2) {
        $('#match').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
      } else {
        $('#match').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
      }

      if(noValido.test(p1 || p2)){ // se chequea el regex de que el string no tenga espacio
        $('#blank').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
      } else {
        $('#blank').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
      }
    }

  }).focus(function() {
      $('#pswd_info').show();
  }).blur(function() {
    $('#pswd_info').hide();
  });

});
```

Ojalá te sirva, cualquier duda o sugerencia me la comentas, saludos!!

Comment: En general me funcionó, cambie el operador en     // se chequea el regex de que el string no tenga espacio
      if(noValido.test(p1 && p2)){ para que revisará ambos campos.
Sin embargo noto que si utilizo más de 8 espacios me valida la regla de 8 caracteres - //validar longitud contraseña
if ( password.length < 8 ) {
    $('#length').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
} else {
    $('#length').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
}
 - Creo que evaluaré primero los espacios antes de todo lo demás, aunque no se si cubra el caso del todo.

Comment: Tienes que intentar tapar todos los huecos, sí validas que sea mayor a 8 caracteres, entonces valida cuando sea menos, y así, igual probando te das cuenta que te faltan cosas, asi que pruebalo de multiples formas pensables

Answer (score 1):

Lo ideal es usar una expresión regular para validar todos los casos que comentas.

Si deseas que tu contraseña en ambos campos cumpla estos casos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

puedes usar la expresión regular:

```
var regex =/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])\w{8,}$/;
```

la cual valida contraseñas de al menos una letra, al menos un numero, al menos una letra mayúscula, al menos 8 caracteres, no permite espacios.

Este es un ejemplo usando la `Regexp` y validando campos para confirmar el valor de la contraseña:

```js
  function checkPassword(valor){
    var myregex = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}$/; 
   if(myregex.test(valor)){
       alert(valor+" es valido :-) !");
       return true;        
   }else{
      alert(valor+" NO es valido!");
       return false;        
   }   
 }

  function checkForm(form){
    if(form.username.value == "") {
      alert("Error: Debe escribir Usuario!");
      form.username.focus();
      return false;
    }
    re = /^\w+$/;
    if(!re.test(form.username.value)) {
      alert("Error: Nombre de usuario debe contener únicamente letras, numeros y underscores!");
      form.username.focus();
      return false;
    }
    if(form.pwd1.value != "" && form.pwd1.value == form.pwd2.value) {
      if(!checkPassword(form.pwd1.value)) {
        alert("La contraseña no es valida!");
        form.pwd1.focus();
        return false;
      }
    } else {
      alert("Error: las contraseñas no coinciden!");
      form.pwd1.focus();
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
```

```html
<form method="POST" action="/.../" onsubmit="checkForm(this); return false;">
<p>Usuario: <input type="text" name="username"></p>
<p>Contraseña: <input type="password" name="pwd1"></p>
<p>Confirmar Contraseña: <input type="password" name="pwd2"></p>
<p><input type="submit" value="verificar"></p>
</form>
```

Revisa el documento :

**[JavaScript: validación de contraseña con expresiones regulares y HTML5](https://www.the-art-of-web.com/javascript/validate-password/)**